# How to create a user1, user2 and 3 others like this post?

Tags: views, flags

I'm creating a website and there is a problem that I have encountered. I need to create list of posts. And each posts have a like button and shows who's liked the post exactly as in Facebook. The likes are handled by the flag module. The list of posts is in a view. What I need to do is figuring out each nid every post has in the view and pull the latest likes and the number of likes each post have.

Comment: Fivestar module have hooks to load this. http://drupal.org/project/fivestar

Answer (score 1):

If this is already in a view -- you can do the flag/like counts by adding a relationship to the view (I'm assuming you're on Drupal 7).  Add the 'Flags: Node flag counter' relationship and select the flag you want the counts for.

Then you can add, for each piece of content in your block or page, the 'Flags: flag counter' field.  That'll appear only once you've added the relationship.  Make sure to select for it to use the relationship.

Let me know if this doesn't make sense and I can elaborate a little more.  :-)

Comment: This is not what I looked for. This only mentions the count not the name of the users who liked the post